# Multi-language stemming in Haystack with ElasticSearch

Tags: django, multilingual, django-haystack, stemming

I'd like to set stemming language on a per-user basis in Django Haystack with ElasticSearch as backend.

In our Django model, we have image objects, that contain comma-separated tag charfield for English, Spanish, German, ...: tags_en, tags_es, tags_de, etc.

Spanish users should be searching only in tags_es and queries should be stemmed also in Spanish.

I couldn't find anything about such a feature and I don't mind tempering inside Haystack's ElasticSearch-backend. Can you point me into the right direction? If there's a solution for Haystack with Solr, that's okay as well.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531447/search-functionality-on-multi-language-django-site