# Django Haystack Whoosh Multilanguage site

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using haystack with whoosh backend in my django project. And my models are multilingual with the modeltranslation module, it creates automatic fields like title_tr, title_en for a field named title...

I am trying to make searches aware of selected language having searched the net and write the below  lines but it is not working for the title_tr, entry_tags_tr fields...
    #search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from aksak.blog.models import Entry

class EntryIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='descr_en', document=True, use_template=True)
    text_tr = indexes.CharField(model_attr='descr_tr')
    title_en = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title_en')
    title_tr = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title_tr')
    tags = indexes.MultiValueField(indexed=True, stored=True, model_attr='entry_tags')

    def get_model(self):
        return Entry


    # haystackCustomQuery.py  !!! IN URLS.PY I AM USING THIS CUSTOM VIEW <-------------

    from django.conf import settings
    from django.utils.translation import get_language
    from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet, DEFAULT_OPERATOR

    class MlSearchQuerySet(SearchQuerySet):
        def filter(self, **kwargs):
            if 'content' in kwargs:
                kwd = kwargs.pop('content')
                currentLngCode = str(get_language())
                lngCode = settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
                if currentLngCode == lngCode: 
                    kwdkey = "text" 
                    kwargs[kwdkey] = kwd
                else:
                    kwdkey = "text_%s" % currentLngCode
                    kwargs[kwdkey] = kwd


            if getattr(settings, 'HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR', DEFAULT_OPERATOR) == 'OR':
               return self.filter_or(**kwargs)
            else:
                return self.filter_and(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, but i think it might be related to the `model_attr` parameters of your `SearchIndex` subclass, which aren't properly resolved by haystack. Try to define some `prepare_<index_fieldname>` methods instead.

I'm including a full example of what i have used in a (German/English) project. Just like you and inspired by [search functionality on multi-language django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531447/search-functionality-on-multi-language-django-site), i got the current language and mapped it to a `SearchIndex` field:

```
from django.conf import settings
from modeltranslation.utils import get_language
from modeltranslation.settings import DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet, DEFAULT_OPERATOR

class ModeltranslationSearchQuerySet(SearchQuerySet):
    def filter(self, **kwargs):
        if 'content' in kwargs:
            kwd = kwargs.pop('content')
            lang = get_language()
            if lang != DEFAULT_LANGUAGE:
                kwdkey = "text_%s" % lang
                kwargs[kwdkey] = kwd
            else:
                kwargs['text'] = kwd
        if getattr(settings, 'HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR', DEFAULT_OPERATOR) == 'OR':
            return self.filter_or(**kwargs)
        else:
            return self.filter_and(**kwargs)
```

In the essence there's one `SearchIndex` field per language, each with its own `prepare_<index_fieldname>` method. Here's a stripped down version of my `search_indexes.py` - it's not really generic, but worked well for my simple requirements:

```
from haystack import indexes

class ContentIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True)  # German (default language)
    text_en = indexes.EdgeNgramField()  # English

    def prepare_text(self, obj):
        return '%s %s' % (obj.title_de, obj.descr_de)

    def prepare_text_en(self, obj):
        return '%s %s' % (obj.title_en, obj.descr_en)
```

Note, that here `text` is used rather than `text_de` for the index field with `document=True` as it is a convention of haystack (you got that right). But inside the `prepare_<index_fieldname>` methods the actual translation fieldnames are used. It also doesn't use a template, but simple string concatenation.

The generic `SearchView` included in haystack (i used 2.0.0-beta) takes a `searchquery` parameter, so the `ModeltranslationSearchQuerySet` can be passed directly through the urls 
setup like this (as far as i understand you have that):

```
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm

url(r'^search/$', SearchView(
    searchqueryset=ModeltranslationSearchQuerySet(), form_class=ModelSearchForm))
```

Final note: I haven't used that code in a while and modeltranslation had some major changes regarding current language awareness. It might very well be that it can be simplified a bit for modeltranslation >=0.6.

Comment: Have you used your actual model fieldnames inside the ``prepare_`` methods? I've updated my example to use your ``descr`` fieldnames.

Comment: Thank you it is working now and i have one small question too... In my search_indexes.py I have:   '  tags = indexes.MultiValueField(indexed=True, stored=True, model_attr='entry_tags') ' which is a tagfield in my entry model. I have tried to add it with prepare method but i got errors -> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting